# How to make a Single Sign On (SSO) using iframes

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-4, watin

I would like to do something like that:

- I will have frame with a bar with buttons of my apps
- I will have a frame with the apps

What I like is that when I click the button in the firs frame it will send the credential to the App. Which approach should I take?

Making http post request? Using a user simulation click like watin?

In the first one I see it is complicated because the cookies. In the second approach I understand watin doesnt work because we need it working in the server side.

Comment: Are all your apps in the same domain?

Comment: So just to get it more clear: you have an ASP.NET MVC application showing a list of buttons. Then you have other ASP.NET MVC applications which are hosted on different domains than the first one. Finally you have an HTML page hosting 2 iframes => 1 hosting the first application and another iframe hosting one of the other MVC applications. And you want when the user clicks on one of the buttons in the first iframe he gets authenticated on the MVC application hosted on the second iframe. Did I get it right?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov totally right!

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - Should I take your absence of response as "it's not possible"? I'm looking to do something similar - though possibly less complicated - but would like to understand where the hang up is in this situation if one exists.